# Microsoft Edge Flags file Location?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft

I wanna Modify Microsoft Edge's Flags For many users
Searched But didn't find any file to modify or something...
Can anyone help ?

Want this to improve performance... Like Disabling smooth-scrolling and much more.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you want and why?

Comment: Flags will most likely be stored in the registry. What are you looking to deploy to multiple clients?

Comment: @Gantendo Edited the post !

Comment: @spikey_richie Registry Key plz ?

Comment: Why are you not using edge://flags directly?

Comment: #sigh. SU doesn't work like that @Programmer.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio cuz I can't do this to a lot of devices !

Comment: If you're managing a lot of computers the correct thing to do is to use Group Policy or SCCM or Intune.